# Android app when try to open web browser stop

Tags: android

when I click button1 to open the url into browser, the application stop. and on debug I get this error:

```
      ![throw new ActivityNotFoundException(][1]
                "No Activity found to handle " + intent);
```

that is the code:

```
package com.example.outroprojeto;
//          
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button; 

public class AtividadePrincipal extends Activity { 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_atividade_principal);
        addButtonClickListner();
    }
    public void addButtonClickListner()
    {

        Button btnNavigator = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnNavigator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg)
            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.satalaj.com"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    } 


}
```

here you cansee the debug screen

Comment: are you testing in emulator?

Comment: you dont have a browser that what the error says but I doubt it this code works perfectly for me

Comment: Thanks Pankaj the problem is the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try using XML. Create a buttonon in Xml and add the android:onClick="browseWeb" then add the following code in Java activity.

```
 public void brosweWeb (View view) {
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW 
 Uri.parse("web address here"));
 startActivity(intent);
```